# No veo los cambios de CSS en mi Pagina Web desarrollando en Android

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy tratando de desarrollar desde el vs code en una tablet samsung con Android, pero los cambios de diseño del CSS no los toma la pagina web, por defecto la tablet abre el html en Chrome.

Edito el html así:

```css
div{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background: blue;
    display: block;
}


* {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Tamborcito Encantadoo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/internal-storage/DCIM/curso.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/internal-storage/DCIM/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>ESTO ES UNA PRUEBA
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Todos los cambios que hago en el html los toma la pagina, pero nada de lo que hago en el css funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que sea tema de cache o del recurso como tal.

Clic derecho > Ver Código Fuente > Busca los enlaces CSS y clic en ellos. Se deben abrir correctamente, sino lo hacen es que o están debidamente referenciados y debes arreglar la ruta.

Si lo hacen los refrescas y pueda que eso borre el cache del navegador y te ayude a visualizar los cambios en el HTML.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es abrir tu pagina en una ventana de incognito de Chrome esto ayudará a no tener tanto cache como la ventana normal y podrás ver los cambios.

Puedes probar a usar algún tipo de CDN también.

Answer (score 0):

Según se menciona en [esta pregunta](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220400), los archivos HTML no cargan completamente al abrirlos desde Chrome aparentemente por los [cambios de privacidad](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes) hechos en Android 10.

La forma que encontré de esquivar el problema fue montar un servidor local en el dispositivo, pudiendo acceder mediante localhost.

Puedes utilizar alguna app como [Simple HTTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phlox.simpleserver).

Comment: No me sabía esta. Quedo pendiente para ver si por ahí va la cosa.